# Change background colour and action bar colour separately

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change my background colour for my app and the actionBar to different colours:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="actionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/veniceblue</item>


</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_template</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@color/veniceblue</item>
</style>
```

But in my manifest file i add :

```
 android:theme="@style/actionBar">
```

But I'm not sure how to add the background at the same time?
I do want it to be set for the whole application??

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if i didn't understand your question (i'm just a beginner trying to learn and help )
you can use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppCompaTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks will give it ago

Comment: I don't have a layout.xml, so how do I set the action bar for the whole app? Or do I just create a new xml and add it itn?

Comment: create a actionbarlayout.xml   then include it in any layout you want
<include layout="@layout/actionbarlayout"/>

Comment: How would I add it to the whole application?